# Bash / Take value from .sh file

Tags: bash

I have `.sh` file: `a.sh`

In this script, In the last line, I have the next:

```
rt = $(bash ...).
```

I want to get this rt. I try to do the next:

`bash a.sh` or `echo $(bash a.sh)`, but it doesn't present the `rt` value.

Comment: `a.sh` was running in a subshell. do you have privilege to modify  the `a.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can source your script in order to run it in the same context of your interactive session:

```
source a.sh && echo ${rt}
```

Comment: I thought of `source` too. however, I feel not so safe. well it depends on what stuffs are in a.sh...

Comment: @Kent - I can't imagine a case where `a.sh` would be safer than `source a.sh`. And if there is one, you still can spawn a subshell, just to source `a.sh`.

Comment: what if `a.sh` has a call to `exit` ? :P

Comment: e.g. in a.sh, change system variable, or , there was an if/else check, if some-condidtion, then `exit` ...  subshell then source is better.

Answer (score 3):

Put `echo rt` at the end of your script to print it to the standard output.

If you can't modify the original script you can use

```
source a.sh && echo ${rt}
```

as already mentioned by @mouviciel but for additional safety (and not to overwrite your `env`) you can use it in a one more subshell

```
bash
source a.sh && echo ${rt}
exit
```

Or `$(source a.sh && echo ${rt})`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't modify the script.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't say that originally. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with "." (e.g. `. ./a.sh`). In this way no new [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will be launched and `rt` variable will be present in the caller environment. Be aware this way other variables can be set and/or modified. This can cause problems.